# Is a Tenant Entitled to a Jury Trial in an Eviction Case?

Tags: united-states, court, jury, new-jersey, eviction

Is a tenant entitled to request a jury trial?

If yes, does it matter if the tenant is being evicted for nonpayment of rent vs. the Summary Dispossess Act in an owner occupied premises?

Comment: You've asking multiple questions about a certain situation. While they are written in a sufficiently hypothetical way to not be legal advice, someone in such a situation would be far better off consulting a professional than random people on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Usually there is not a right to a jury trial in a possession hearing. This is in part because the possession hearing is preliminary, with a hearing that addresses matters such as damages in a final hearing. But, once a tenant has been evicted, the possession question becomes moot.

Answer (score 2):

You might find this helpful, it suggests most states do allow a jury trial.

["Survey of State Laws Governing the Right to Trial by Jury in Eviction Proceedings"](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4252792)

Full document [here](https://deliverypdf.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=347005106102013005093119018120003000009034067081071060081071023000116068089064011073126035037037025005058018006068095122096022060073073001035007005099107127018004127081002001029095094114118090092064087085081085091017080111125087121078070079009075070103&EXT=pdf&INDEX=TRUE).